# Problem in using useReducer and useContext hooks to make a shopping cart

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a shopping cart using the useReducer and useContext hook but I'm facing an issue.When I click on Add button I want products to be displayed one under another in the Cart screen but when I add the products in the cart, are not displayed. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is my homepage file where I listed the products :

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer, useContext } from 'react';
import '../components/components.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import logger from 'use-reducer-logger';
import { Store } from '../Store';


  const { state, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const { cart } = state;
  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    const existItem = cart.cartItems.find((x) => x._id === product.id);
    const quantity = existItem ? existItem.quantity + 1 : 1;

    ctxDispatch({
      type: 'CART_ADD_ITEM',
      payload: { ...product, quantity },
    });
  };

 
export default Products;


 If somebody can give me a tip it would be nice
```

Answer (score 0):

you have some issue with your logic in the dispatch to add to cart I made the respective modifications:

```js
 const addToCartHandler = (item) => {
    const existItem = cart.cartItems.find((x) => x._id === item.id);
    const quantity = existItem ? existItem.quantity + 1 : 1;

    ctxDispatch({
      type: 'CART_ADD_ITEM',
      payload: { ...item, quantity },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="produse">
      {products.map((item) => (
        <div className="produs" key={item._id}>
          <div>
            <img className="imagine-produs" src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
          </div>

          <div>
            <h3 className="nume-produs">{item.name} </h3>
          </div>
          <div className="pret-produs">{item.price} RON</div>

          <div>
            <button className="adauga-produs" onClick={()=>addToCartHandler(item)}>
              Adauga
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Be aware that in order to be able to run it locally I needed to drop *logger*

Comment: I changed:  ** <button className="adauga-produs" onClick={()=>addToCartHandler(item)}> ** and 
** const addToCartHandler = (item) => { **

Answer (score 0):

in my think, `existItem` is going to be changed as following:

```
const addToCartHandler = (item) => {
    const existItem = cart.cartItems.find((x) => x._id === item.id);
    const quantity = existItem ? existItem.quantity + 1 : 1;

    ctxDispatch({
      type: 'CART_ADD_ITEM',
      payload: { ...item, quantity },
    });
 };
 ...
};
```